# Seam carving tool like seamonster

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

Is there a picture compression tool for Ubuntu more or less equivalent to [seamonster](http://seamonster.codeplex.com/) for MS Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [Liquid Rescale for GIMP](http://liquidrescale.wikidot.com/) is a popular implementation of the Avidan-Shamir seam-carving image manipulation function.

Comment: Is there something that can do batches of images at once.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) has [support for Liquid Rescale](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10582). And [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is all about batches :)

Answer (score 0):

If you install the `gimp-plugin-registry` package in Ubuntu, it contains the "Liquid Rescale" plugin that msw mentions.

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```

Unfortunately I don't know a simple to use batch processor for the GIMP that can use this plugin, but if you're good at scripting, the GIMP allows you to do about everything from scripting.